# Querying firebase database at onwrite event

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to write a firebase function which will check the the "user" and behave according to that on database write event. However when i query the database it returns null everytime and i didnt figure out what i am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

My realtime database structure is like this:

```
ilk-projemiz-cd55baddclose
 users
   edRIPg8BcZU9YPbubp7HtQo7phl1
     sayilar: 1532
     status:  "on"
   hakan
     sayilar:  5000
     status:  "waiting"
   mehmet
     sayilar:  7000
     status:  "on"
```

My firebase function file is this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.sayi = functions.database.ref("/users/{uid}/status").onWrite(event => {
    const status = event.data.val();
    var user = event.data.ref.parent.key;
    if (status =="on") {
        console.log(status);
        const events = event.data.adminRef.child('users');
        const query =events.orderByChild('status').equalTo('on').limitToFirst(2);
        query.on("value", sorunsuz,sorunlu);
    }
});

function sorunlu(error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong.");
    console.log(error);
}

function sorunsuz(data) {
    console.log("11111");
    var fruits = data.val();
    console.log(fruits); //it returns null here
    var keys = Object.keys(fruits);
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
      var key = keys[i];
      if(key==user){
        //console.log(fruits[key].sayilar);
        console.log("aaa");
      }else{
        console.log("bbbb");
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you listening path is wrong "/users/{uid}/status"', **I think, you have to listen to users node**

Comment: What is `exports.sayi` trying to accomplish?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i am trying to match users with each other so when a users logs in his/her status field becomes on but for not matching his own userid i am getting userid from onwrite event at status field then after query (as there is no not equal in realtime database) i will exclude persons userid from gathered query results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:  `const events = event.data.adminRef.child('users');` tries to access a `users` node under the `status` node. And I think what you wanted to do is access the users node under the root reference.

Use the Admin SDK instead:

```
const events = admin.database().child('users');
```

**Update**: the `user` variable is out of scope, so I suggest you move the `sorunsuz()` function to be inside the `on()` function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sayi = functions.database.ref("/users/{uid}/status").onWrite(event => {
    const status = event.data.val();
    var user = event.data.ref.parent.key;
    if (status =="on") {
        console.log(status);
        const events = admin.database().child('users');
        const query =events.orderByChild('status').equalTo('on').limitToFirst(2);
        query.on("value",
         function(data) {
            console.log("11111");
            var fruits = data.val();
            console.log(fruits); //it returns null here
            var keys = Object.keys(fruits);
            for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                var key = keys[i];
                if(key==user){
                    //console.log(fruits[key].sayilar);
                    console.log("aaa");
                }else{
                    console.log("bbbb");
                }
            }
        }, sorunlu);
    }
});

function sorunlu(error) {
    console.log("Something went wrong.");
    console.log(error);
}
```

Comment: if i use admin sdk it gives the fallowing error 
 Error: The default Firebase app does not exist. Make sure you call initializeApp() before using any of the Firebase services.
    at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)

Comment: at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:119:28)
    at FirebaseNamespaceInternals.app (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:93:19)
    at FirebaseNamespace.serviceNamespace [as database] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-namespace.js:157:32)
    at exports.sayi.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:9:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:59:27)
    at next (native)

Comment: at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:28:71

Comment: You must initialize the admin SDK. Use this line `admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);` after `const admin = require('firebase-admin');`

Comment: Thanks @Rosário Pereira Fernandes , after adding that line and changing const events = admin.database().child('users'); to const events = admin.database().ref('users'); it started to work however my functions doesnt recognise user variable (i guess it is out of its scope) how should i pass it to the function near data?

Answer (score 1):

you have to listen to users node

functions.database.ref("/users/{uid}/status"),
this path is not exist anywhere thats why you are getting null.

```
exports.sayi = functions.database.ref("/users").onWrite(event => {
   const status = event.data.val(); //this data will be new
   //Use above value to refer things

   if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
     //Update operation
  }

});
```

Comment: but i dont want the function run everytime anything changes under users node, i just want it to run when status node changes.